# If ACF date picker field value reached, delete row

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using the following code for a repeater field, which also has a datepicker. I would like hide the loops that are older than the current date.

```
<?php  if( have_rows('jobs','option') ): ?>
            <div id="jobs">
                <div class="jobs-title">
                    <h2><?php the_field('active','option'); ?></h2>
                </div>
                <div class="jobs">
                    <div class="inner-jobs flexing">
                        <?php while( have_rows('jobs','option') ): the_row(); ?>
                        <div class="flex job flexing">
                            <div class="flex-small">
                                <div class="bubble flex">
                                    <img src="<?php the_sub_field('job-img','option'); ?>">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex-cont">
                                <div class="job-title"><h4><?php the_sub_field('job-title','option'); ?></h4></div>
                                <p>Lõpptähtaeg: <?php the_sub_field('job-deadline','option'); ?></p>
                                <a href="<?php the_sub_field('job-url','option'); ?>" target="_blank"><button><?php the_sub_field('job-button','option'); ?><span class="ion-ios-arrow-forward"></span></button></a>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- job -->
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                    </div><!-- inner -->
                </div><!-- .jobs -->
            </div><!-- #jobs -->
            <?php endif;?>
```

The datepicker field is 'job-deadline'

Haven't yet found a good example, any advise?

**EDIT: managed to reached the following, which still outputs 70/01/01**

```
<?php  if( have_rows('jobs','option') ): ?>
        <?php $now = time(); ?>
        <?php $date_one_timestamp = strtotime(get_sub_field('job-deadline','option')); ?>
            <div id="jobs">
                <div class="jobs-title">
                    <h2><?php the_field('active','option'); ?></h2>
                </div>
                <div class="jobs">
                    <div class="inner-jobs flexing">
                        <?php while( have_rows('jobs','option') ): the_row(); ?>
                        <?php if ($now > $date_one_timestamp ) { ?>
                        <div class="flex job flexing">
                            <div class="flex-small">
                                <div class="bubble flex">
                                    <img src="<?php the_sub_field('job-img','option'); ?>">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex-cont">
                                <div class="job-title"><h4><?php the_sub_field('job-title','option'); ?></h4></div>
                                <p>Lõpptähtaeg: <?php echo date("y/m/d", $date_one_timestamp); ?></p>
                                <a href="<?php the_sub_field('job-url','option'); ?>" target="_blank"><button><?php the_sub_field('job-button','option'); ?><span class="ion-ios-arrow-forward"></span></button></a>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- job -->
                        <?php } else { ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                    </div><!-- inner -->
                </div><!-- .jobs -->
            </div><!-- #jobs -->
            <?php endif;?>
```

Comment: get current date from php in yymmdd format, put that up against your datepicker (with the same format). In your loop, you can then if($jquerydate >= $currentdate) { /*do your stuff here*/ }

Comment: Hi, I updated my EDIT accordingly. Unfortunately it is outputting 70/01/01

Answer (score 0):

Try the below, untested...

```
 <?php  if( have_rows('jobs','option') ): ?>
                <div id="jobs">
                    <div class="jobs-title">
                        <h2><?php the_field('active','option'); ?></h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="jobs">
                        <div class="inner-jobs flexing">
                            <?php while( have_rows('jobs','option') ): the_row(); ?>
                            <?php if(strtotime(get_sub_field('job-deadline','option'))<time()) { ?>
                            <div class="flex job flexing">
                                <div class="flex-small">
                                    <div class="bubble flex">
                                        <img src="<?php the_sub_field('job-img','option'); ?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="flex-cont">
                                    <div class="job-title"><h4><?php the_sub_field('job-title','option'); ?></h4></div>
                                    <p>Lõpptähtaeg: <?php echo date("y/m/d", $date_one_timestamp); ?></p>
                                    <a href="<?php the_sub_field('job-url','option'); ?>" target="_blank"><button><?php the_sub_field('job-button','option'); ?><span class="ion-ios-arrow-forward"></span></button></a>
                                </div>
                            </div><!-- job -->
                            <?php } else { ?>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                        </div><!-- inner -->
                    </div><!-- .jobs -->
                </div><!-- #jobs -->
        <?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately didn't get a result, stilld displaying all the fields.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of the `have_rows()` loop:

```
if ( date('d-m-Y', strtotime(get_sub_field('job-deadline','option'))) == "date('d-m-Y', strtotime('now')) ) {
continue;
}
```

Convert the job-deadline date and the current date to the same format and compare. Use `continue;` to skip to the next row in the loop.